# Euler's formula, level of reflection at surface for bouncing ball python

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code below models perfect reflection of a bouncing ball. What would model 90%?

```
for i in range (steps):
   t[i+1] = t[i] + dt
   x[i+1] = x[i] + v[i]*dt
   v[i+1] = v[i] - g*dt
   if x[i+1] < 0.0:    # if ball is below surface, reflect it
      x[i+1] = -x[i+1]
      v[i+1] = -v[i+1]
```

Comment: Source: http://astro.physics.ncsu.edu/urca/course_files/Lesson01/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
  v[i+1] = -v[i+1]
```

is equivalent to

```
  v[i+1] *= -1
```

So try

```
  v[i+1] *= -0.9
```